# Dynamic json object with string keys

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have added a dynamic json object with javascript. the code is as follow:

```
if (!beadz[color.title])
    beadz.push({
    (color.title): {
        bead.title: {
            "inventoryQuantity": bead.inventory_quantity,
            "currentQuantity": 1
        }
    }
});
```

However the code is not working and giving syntax error. what i am missing?
kindly help.

Comment: please provide the json you are using

Comment: Why don't you tell us *what* syntax error you get?

Comment: `(color.title):` is invalid syntax. Did you mean `[color.title]:`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ES6

```
if(!beadz[color.title])

                beadz.push({[color.title]:{[bead.title]:{"inventoryQuantity":bead.inventory_quantity,"currentQuantity":1}}});
```